# Why does the calculated return from summary table can not show in Line Chart in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, linechart

I face the problem where I created measure which has formula like below:

```
# Mixing Class =
VAR Temp =
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Mixing Class',
        'Mixing Class'[ClassKey],
        "NumClassTCMixing", DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK ( 'Mixing Class'[TC_TeacherCode] )
    )
RETURN
    COUNTX ( FILTER ( Temp, [NumClassTCMixing] >= 4 ), 'Mixing Class'[ClassKey] )
```

After this I drag this measure to Line Chart which show the total number of Classes through time. But the Chart show nothing (No error, No data). What is the problem here? Does my DAX code has errors? Please help me because I spend all day to fix this but nothing changes :(

This is the sample of columns in my measure:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This construction is more safety, try it.

```
# Mixing Class = 
VAR Temp = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'Mixing Class'
            ,'Mixing Class'[ClassKey]
       )
       ,"numOfTeachers",CALCULATE(
                            COUNTROWS(
                                DISTINCT('Mixing Class'[TC_TeacherCode])  
                            )
                         )
                     -- CALCULATE(
                     --     DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(
                     --         'Mixing Class'[TC_TeacherCode]
                     -- ) -- should return the same result
RETURN 
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            Temp
            ,[numOfTeachers]>= 4
        )
     )
```

Alternative:

```
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        VALUES('Mixing Class')
        , VAR dateInChart = SELECTEDVALUE(Date[DateKey])
          RETURN
              CALCULATE(
                  COUNTROWS(
                      DISTINCT('Mixing Class'[TC_TeacherCode])  
                   )
                   ,'Mixing Class'[DateKey]=dateInChart 
              )>=4
)
```

Comment: and filter the ``DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK`` on the visual :D

Comment: @Mik Thank you for your help <3 First I have tried your code and unlucky it still does not show nothing! It is weird when it still show in Card Visualization Component but Line Chart is empty. Second I have to use the measure without just 'DISTINCOUNTNOBLANK' because as you saw in my measure there is condition where # of 'TC_TeacherCode' must greater or equal to 4

Comment: Hi, I altered the code, please try again.

Comment: Hi @Mik, I have tried again and there is one misunderstanding is TC_TeacherCode has to be counted because the logic is compare its number of TC_TeacherCode >= 4.
After changes a bit I found this: When I change to >=1, drag it to Card it shows 1683 but when I drag to Line Chart it shows total 50860 (I change to Table to view the Total). And of course when change back to >=4 it show nothing in Line Chart but still show in Card

Comment: It would be easer to understand  what to do with pbix file. Or, if you provide a table. I mean it can be many reasons why the measure doesn't work. And it would be much faster to get the result with a data and its model

Comment: @Mik Hi, it hard to be send .pbix file because its data is store in AS and has set up for security, but I have attached the sample data in the question. :(

Comment: What do you have in the Date column (X-axis).? Could you please attach the image?

Comment: How many tables are involved into the measure/visual? If you have a Calendar table are tables linked?

Comment: @Mik Hi, there are only 2 tables (Calendar & MixClass) are involved in the measure. Yes, the Calendar table has been linked to the MixClass table. In detail I have already create other measures which can be filter by the Date Slicer but only the measure calculate total Mixing Classes above can not be filtered :( . It is very weird since it still shows data when I drag it into Card rather than Line Chart

Comment: Hi, I updated measures. Please, ensures that data types in linked columns are the same, both are numbers or both are text. I have experienced a problem like that - when a measure didn't work due to data type difference. If this wont work, then I can help only if it will be a dummy file.  And, please, check measures with 1-3 values.